# Master sound volume in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, sound, music

I have been searching everywhere for master volume for sound and music in LibGDX but to no avail. Can anyone tell me if it is implemented somewhere or do i need to implement such functionality myself? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty new to LibGDX but I don't think it would be too hard to implement your own version of a "master volume" - just have a float variable called master volume and then use it whenever you play your music and edit it how you please.

For example:

```
public static float mastervol = 1f;

//playing your sounds
sound1.play(mastervol);
sound2.play(mastervol);

//change your master vol
public void setMasterVolume(float i){mastervol = i;}
```

Something along those lines.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, i created my own and it's working perfectly! :D

Comment: @AVariable If you did what he suggested and it worked, then mark his answer as the accepted one!

Comment: @AVariable just click the checkmark next to the number on the side of this answer

Comment: I did it! :D i'm pretty knew to stackexchange, thanks guys!